# How can I access a man page that is masked by another man page?

Tags: man

I installed a locally compiled version of OpenSSL and I forgot to skip the man pages. Now I can't access the man page for the OS's `passwd(1)`.

- OS: Raspberry's Debian Stretch (with GUI)
- OpenSSL: 1.1.1g

Using `apropos` gave me a hint that there are also extensions to be browsed with `-e` flag (`man man`):

```
passwd(1)    - change user password
passwd(1ssl) - compute password hashes
```

However, none of the following worked for me

- `man passwd`
- `man 1 passwd` (from answer but still doesn't work)
- `man -s 1 passwd`
- `man -s 1 -e '' passwd`
- `man -s 1 -e posix passwd`

It seems that man will default to the `ssl` extension, which makes me wonder... How can I look at the original `passwd(1)` man page?

**Note: no uninstalling allowed.**

Comment: What Operating System is it?

Comment: I am working on an R-Pi with Debian Buster

Comment: Can you please share the output of `man -f passwd` (which should list `passwd(1)` and `passwd(1ssl)`, as you already posted) and `man -aw passwd`? (Hoping your `man` version supports these options). I suspect you have two files named `passwd.1.gz` (actually, more than one `passwd.1`, with an optional extension) in distinct directories and that your question has been misread.

Comment: Depending on your `man` implementation you may be interested in [Why man -k or Apropos cannot find some pages while man -a can?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609561/315749)

Answer (score 5):

You were close - don't use *any* flag, just `man <section> command`:

```
$ man 1 passwd
...
$ man 1ssl passwd
...
```

(I confirmed this on Ubuntu 20.04, which happens to default to section 1 when none specified.)

Comment: I hopped into the terminal and tested it. It does not work. `man 1 passwd` still shows the entry for `openssl-passwd`

Comment: That's weird; I've been using the `man` command in that way since 1995 on SunOS. Check `man man` - it should say something like `man [section] command` where _section_ is optional. Do you have `man` aliased in some way? What does `type -f man` tell you?

Comment: `man [man options] [[section] page ...] ...` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html

Comment: `type -f man` outputs `man is /usr/bin/man`

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution with the `-a` flag and skip the OpenSSL page

Comment: If anybody proposes something better, I'll mark it as the answer