# Why man -k or Apropos cannot find some pages while man -a can?

Tags: man, apropos

On my Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS system, if I use `man -aw printf` it will return:

```
/usr/share/fish/man/man1/printf.1
/usr/share/man/man1/printf.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/printf.3.gz
```

But if I use `man -k printf` or `man -f printf` or `apropos printf` it will **only** return information about:

```
/usr/share/man/man1/printf.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/printf.3.gz
```

Why those commands cannot find something that `man -a` can?

I have tried `mandb` and it has nothing to update.

Comment: Which version of `man` are you using? Is it [man-db](https://nongnu.org/man-db/)?

Comment: man 2.9.1 in Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS. I do not know if it is man-db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What follows assumes that your `man` & friends come from [man-db](https://nongnu.org/man-db/). Considering that Pop!_OS is based on Ubuntu and that Ubuntu 20.04 has man-db installed by default, this should be true.

When operating in "whatis" or in "apropos" mode (`man -f` and `man -k`, respectively), `man` actually invokes the `whatis` binary and delegates the search to it. On the other hand, when operating in its default mode (e.g. `man page`) or in "where" mode (`man -w page`), the search is performed by the `man` binary itself. The search routines of `man` and `whatis` are implemented independently of each other.

Two main reasons may make `whatis` list fewer manual pages than `man -a`:

1. incomplete configuration: if the search path configured in `/etc/manpath.config` (used on Debian and derivatives; `/etc/man_db.conf` on some other distributions) includes all the directories containing manual pages on your system but there is no `MANDB_MAP` for some of them in that file, then an index database is not initialized (nor searched, if existing) for them; `man -a` will find the pages they contain anyway, because it directly searches the directories listed in the search path, while `whatis` won't, because it only searches the index database;
2. even when all the directories containing manual pages have proper `MANDATORY_MANPATH` and `MANDB_MAP` entries in `/etc/manpath.config`, `whatis` may still list fewer results than `man -a` because *it simply [omits](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/tree/src/whatis.c?h=2.9.3#n455) duplicate name-section combinations from its output*. In your case, `printf(1)` is found in both `/usr/share/man` and `/usr/share/fish/man` and only the one from the directory that comes first in the search path is listed.

You can use the `manpath` command to display the search path that `man` & friends will use, and make sure it includes all the relevant directories. By default it is built based on the `MANDATORY_MANPATH` entries in `/etc/manpath.config`.

`man` & friends can also be invoked with an explicitly defined search path by setting `MANPATH` to alter the search results. For instance, if you are in case (2),

```
MANPATH=/usr/share/fish/man:/usr/share/man whatis printf
```

will likely print the one-line description for `/usr/share/fish/man/man1/printf.1` and not the one for `/usr/share/man/man1/printf.1.gz`.

You can also look at what is going on under the hood by using the `--debug` option. It will likely show that your programs are using a search path that lists `/usr/share/man` before `/usr/share/fish/man` and that all three files are found, but a line for the second found `printf` in section `1` is just not printed by `whatis` (or `man -f`).

Finally, to address case (2), you may define a helper function that wraps `man` to make it list duplicate name-section combinations too:

```sh
slowman () (
    IFS=:
    for path in ${MANPATH-$(manpath)}
    do
        printf '%s\n' "Searching ${path}:" 1>&2
        MANPATH="$path" man "$@"
    done
)
```

Comment: Now I know this is happening because there is 2 search implementations. This answers the question.

And I do not have `/etc/man_db.conf` but I have `/etc/manpath.config`.

My `manpath` was `/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man` when I asked the question. Now I updated by inserting `MANDATORY_MANPATH  /usr/share/fish/man` + `mandb` and `manpath` has `:/usr/man/fish/man` now. Even with this `whatis` cannot find the manual inside `/usr/man/fish`.

Comment: @JonasA.Xavier Answer edited to reflect the config file path on your distribution. Note that 1) you also need `MANDB_MAP` entries in `/etc/manpath.config` to make `whatis` work; 2) `whatis` will ever show only _one_ `printf(1)` result - the first one found in the directories listed in `MANPATH` when you invoke it.

Comment: I got `/usr/share/man/man1/exa.1.gz` and `/usr/share/man/man4/exa.4.gz`, `man exa` gets exa.1.gz, but `man -k exa` only gets exa.4.gz not both of them, is there anything I can do to make `man -k exa` show both exa, or use another tool to list both exa?

Comment: @CodyChan Never mind, the man-db is not updated since I install exa seconds ago, I just need to update man-db manually

Answer (score 0):

man man:

```
   -w, --where, --path, --location
          Don't actually display the manual page, but do print  the  loca‐
          tion  of  the source nroff file that would be formatted.  If the
          -a option is also used, then print the locations of  all  source
          files that match the search criteria.
```

Comment: I believe the `-a` flag description is more to the point. But what about `apropos`?

Comment: If I use only `man -a` same thing happens. It will find all 3 manual pages. I used `man -aw` just for demonstration.

Comment: @Quasímodo `apropos` is the same as `man -k`. And it will not find all the manual pages.

Answer (score 0):

Depends  on your exact version of `man(1)` (I very much doubt it is the original Unix one...), and on configuration (`MANPATH` environment variable, contents on `/etc/man_db.conf` for Linux' -- Debian's really -- version, ...).