# apropos does not find cmp

Tags: apropos

Why can't `apropos` find `cmp`? I clearly see both search words on `cmp` man page. I've tried to run `sudo mandb -c` just in case with no apprarent changes. I've tried web search, read [Why man -k or Apropos cannot find some pages while man -a can?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609561/why-man-k-or-apropos-cannot-find-some-pages-while-man-a-can) however do not see how it can apply to my case.

```
$ man cmp
NAME
       GNU cmp - compare two files byte by byte

SYNOPSIS
       cmp [OPTION]... FILE1 [FILE2 [SKIP1 [SKIP2]]]

DESCRIPTION
       Compare two files byte by byte.
```

But:

```
~$ man -k files | grep -i compare
bzcmp (1)            - compare bzip2 compressed files
bzdiff (1)           - compare bzip2 compressed files
comm (1)             - compare two sorted files line by line
git-diff-files (1)   - Compares files in the working tree and the index
lzcmp (1)            - compare compressed files
lzdiff (1)           - compare compressed files
mcomp (1)            - Compares two files using mtools
ntfscmp (8)          - compare two NTFS filesystems and tell the differences
xzcmp (1)            - compare compressed files
xzdiff (1)           - compare compressed files
zcmp (1)             - compare compressed files
zdiff (1)            - compare compressed files
~$ apropos -a files compare
bzcmp (1)            - compare bzip2 compressed files
bzdiff (1)           - compare bzip2 compressed files
comm (1)             - compare two sorted files line by line
git-diff-files (1)   - Compares files in the working tree and the index
lzcmp (1)            - compare compressed files
lzdiff (1)           - compare compressed files
mcomp (1)            - Compares two files using mtools
ntfscmp (8)          - compare two NTFS filesystems and tell the differences
xzcmp (1)            - compare compressed files
xzdiff (1)           - compare compressed files
zcmp (1)             - compare compressed files
zdiff (1)            - compare compressed files
```

Comment: It does for me! What version of mandb are you running? On what system?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, mandb 2.9.1, Linux Mint 20.2

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', yes, I have ver 3.7. Is it hard to upgrade and not wait for new distro version?

Comment: Diffutils is a core package and this is a very minor bug, so I would not recommend upgrading outside the distribution.